# How do you configure a VS2015 C# project to put the NuGet packages on build in a lib directory?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. I have got a C# project with a bunch of NuGet packages. When I build the project the NuGet assemblies get copied into `bin\Release` but I don't want them in the root directory of my application, I want them to be put in a `lib` subdirectory.

The `output path` build setting doesn't do what I want, it changes the general output directory. I think that it's Visual Studio which copies the NuGet assemblies on build.

I like my projects organized and don't want a bunch of dependency DLLs in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is that you could think about using the init.ps1. When the NuGet package is installed for the first time or every time the solution is re-opened in Visual Studio, Init.ps1 will runs once for your solution.

Reference Ryan Vice's share us the detailed steps about how to let NuGet copy dlls to [solution root]\lib in this case:

[How to copy Nuget content files relative to the solution root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320618/how-to-copy-nuget-content-files-relative-to-the-solution-root)